# Qual a função de carácter ? no tipo de variável em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem

Vejo muitos códigos de terceiros e vejo frequentemente a utilização do sinal de interrogação no tipo da variável.

Exemplo:

```
public bool? Status
```

Alguém poderia me explicar qual a diferença de não se ter esse sinal `?` no tipo de dado *bool*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isso é açúcar sintático pra *nullables* (tipos anuláveis). Equivale a:

```
public Nullable<bool> Status
```

É uma forma de você ter uma variável que pode conter uma referência nula ou um valor. Os tipos por valor (inteiro, booleano, datas etc.), por padrão, não podem conter referências nulas.

Mais informações [no manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

Comment: Hmmm.... entendi boa resposta vou passar a usar isso para poder fazer comparações de nulls. Obrigado!